# Textures not displaying correctly C++ opengl SOIL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, soil

Here is my problem;

Image a box, or a cube, all sides right.

If we were to put the box on a flat surface, the face touching the bottom, would be the floor or base. if the base had an inside, which most boxes do, from the outside you would not be able to see it right.

Unfortunately, in my code you can. instead of a box, you have a room, in which i go outside the room and see the floor, but i should not.

ill post an image of the problem and a video, as well as some code and any code that you might ask for.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ml3-OBGNXXA&feature=youtu.be

http://www.flickr.com/photos/pkerkm/8607171993/

http://www.flickr.com/photos/pkerkm/8608276014/

//here is how i manage the textures

```
void /*GraphicsEngine::*/drawWall(double a[3],double b[3], double c[3], double d[3], bool floor){
if(floor){
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
}else{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
}
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
//gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data); // build our texture mipmaps
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_DECAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_DECAL);
//glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3dv(a);
    glTexCoord2d(-1.0,0.0);
    glVertex3dv(d);
    glTexCoord2d(-1.0,-1.0);
    glVertex3dv(c);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,-1.0);
    glVertex3dv(b);
glEnd();
}
```

//here is the reshape function

```
void reshape(int w, int h){
    //glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    //glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, 1.0, 200.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.6);
   //glLoadIdentity();
}
```

//here is the display function

```
void /*GraphicsEngine::*/display(){
 //glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 //glLoadIdentity ();
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 //glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
 //glClearDepth(1.0);
 //glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 setPos();
 gluLookAt(currentXPos,currentYPos,currentZPos,currentXFace,currentYFace,currentZFace,0,1,0);
 generateMap();
 graphicsFloor();
 int i = 0;
 if(projectiles.size()>0){
    for(i= 0; i< projectiles.size(); i++){
        arrow(projectiles.operator[](i).getXPos(),projectiles.operator[](i).getYPos(),projectiles.operator[](i).getZPos(),0.5,BLOCKWIDTH);
    }
    projectileMotion();
    player.advance();
    //glutPostRedisplay();
 /*}else if(player.advance()){
     glutPostRedisplay();
 }*/
 }
 //glFlush();
 glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

//here is what tells where to draw the floor and the walls

```
void graphicsFloor(){
int x,z;
//up

for(x=0;x<7;x+=7){
    for(z=0;z<105;z+=7){
        double a[3] = {x,0,z};
        double b[3] = {x+7,0,z};
        double c[3] = {x+7,0,z+7};
        double d[3] = {x,0,z+7};
        drawWall(d,a,b,c,true);
    }
}
}
```

// the walls

```
void generateMap(){
int z;
int x;
for(z =0;z<105;z+=7){
      double a[3] = {0,0,z};
      double b[3] = {0,0,z+7};
      double c[3] = {0,MAPHEIGHT,z+7};
      double d[3] = {0,MAPHEIGHT,z};
      drawWall(d,a,b,c,false);
}
for(z =0;z<42;z+=7){
      double a[3] = {7,0,z};
      double b[3] = {7,0,z+7};
      double c[3] = {7,MAPHEIGHT,z+7};
      double d[3] = {7,MAPHEIGHT,z};
      drawWall(d,a,b,c,false);
}
}
```

//and here is how i load up the textures

```
void genTex(){

texture[0]=SOIL_load_OGL_texture // load an image file directly as a new OpenGL texture 
    (
        //"C:\\Users\\Eddy\\Desktop\\Senior Project\\Senior Project\\bloodwall2.png",
        "C:\\Users\\Pkerkm\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\files\\gameprojecgraphics\\bloodwall2.png",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
        //SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO| SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS| SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA| SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT| SOIL_FLAG_DDS_LOAD_DIRECT| SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y

    );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
}
```

Comment: What's with `projectiles.operator[](i)` rather than `projectiles[i]`?

Comment: i am not sure, its my partners code, but i tried what you said, and both do the same thing. no difference, but i shorter is always better, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like depth testing is disabled. Enable it:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

If that doesn't work, make sure you have a depth buffer and try again.

Comment: where exactly would that go?

Comment: @Pkerkm: It depends, but probably at the bottom of `reshape` or the top of `display`.

Comment: it works well on reshape and display. ill only keep one though, so there is no redundancy. Thank you @icktofay THANK YOU